# Node script doesn't create file when executed from another script

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm running an Express server that receives a JSON through a POST request, then saves it into a file called test.json, then launches another script called demo.js that reads the test.json, does some calculations and then writes a file called result.json in its working directory. The express server at this point should read the result.json created by demo.js and then send it back to the server that made the POST request.

Now the problem is that if I execute the demo.js file directly from a terminal  with a node demo.js command it creates the file, whereas it does everything but the file creation when executed from the Express server therefore the server throws an exception as it cannot find the file that has to send back as a response to the POST request.

Here's the code of the Express server:

```
//Function that runs the demo.js script

function runScript(scriptPath, callback) {

// keeps track of whether callback has been invoked to prevent multiple invocatio>    var invoked = false;

var process = childProcess.fork(scriptPath);

// listen for errors as they may prevent the exit event from firing
process.on('error', function (err) {
    if (invoked) return;
    invoked = true;
    callback(err);
});

// execute the callback once the process has finished running
process.on('exit', function (code) {
    if (invoked) return;
    invoked = true;
    var err = code === 0 ? null : new Error('exit code ' + code);
    callback(err);
});

} app.post('/', (req, res) => { console.log("Received");

    fs.writeFile('./solver/src/test.json', JSON.stringify(req.body) , err => {
            if(err){
                    console.error(err);
            }
    });

    runScript('./solver/src/demo.js', function (err) {
            if (!err){
                    fs.readFile('./solver/src/result.json', (err, data) => {
                            if(err) throw err;

                            const jsonResp = JSON.stringify(data);
                            res.send(data);
                            console.log('finished running some-script.js');
                    });}
            else{
                    console.error(err);

            }
    });

});
```

And this is the demo.js file

```
//result is a string generated by previous instructions //contained in the demo.js file, it gets correctly //printed by the console.log at the end of the script

fs.writeFile('./result.json', JSON.stringify(result) , (err) => { 
if(err){ console.error(err); } 
else{ console.log("File created succesfully"); } 
}); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 1));
```

I tried to tinker with the demo.js file by putting a {flag: 'w'} in the writeFile function to no avail.

Comment: `fs.writeFile('./result.json'...` is probably putting the result file in the current working directory, which is probably your express app, since you're calling fork on "./solver/src/demo.js". Try setting the current working directory in your [fork call](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/child_process.html#child_processforkmodulepath-args-options)

Comment: @lucasvw yes it does, that was unexpected. Thank you!

Comment: great! I've added an answer below to document the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling [fork](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/child_process.html#child_processforkmodulepath-args-options) with a full path ('./solver/src/demo.js'), the current working directory for demo.js is the current working directory of your express application. Use the `cwd` option for fork to set the working directory for the forked process to './solver/src/' and you should see the file where you expect it.